# Vue-resource blocked by CORS policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-resource

I know there's some similar treads but no one solution helped me.

I'm building an application with Ruby on Rails and Vue. Currently, I'm trying to get the Spotify access token of my user. So I just have to create a get request and wait for the response.

It works perfectly from a view created with Rails, but not from my Vue app.

This is the error in my console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=261c008xxxxxx52da843b8096d&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fspotify%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=playlist-modify-public+user-read-email&state=5987fec3952e0c46332183c526d0abef2f0d35a13e39694e' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/auth/spotify') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.** but if we check headers:

[image: headers]
In my js file I have:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
  request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  request.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  request.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  request.headers.set('X-CSRF-Token', document.getElementsByName('csrf-token')[0].content);
  next();
});
```

I don't know where to look, would you have an idea?
I already tried to install a chrome extension, allow all origins on my server side, replace Vue-resource with Axios, install cors with node...

Comment: Why are you making an XHR call?

Answer (score 1):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be a *response* header and not a request header. Your backend API must set it.

Comment: Hi @Flame, thanks for your answer. I'm using the Spotify's API and it works with Ruby but not from Vue, this is why I don't understand where is the problem

Comment: the allow-origin header is used by browsers to tell which origins can access the resource (i.e. which domains). When youre making a request from Ruby, that is done serverside and it is not originating from a domain therefore it works. In Javascript the header is checked by the browser and the request can be blocked